# Accessing custom attribute from within an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, attributes

I would like to know if it is possible to get access a custom iframe attribute within the iframe.

I was thinking something along the lines of:
**html1.html**

```
<iframe src="html2.html" customAttr="example"></iframe>
```

**html2.html**

```
<script>alert(window.customAttr);</script>
```

However the variable `window.customAttr` appears undefined.

Does anyone know, how to get about this?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    alert(window.frameElement.getAttribute('customAttr'));
</script>
```

Comment: Anyway to access the custom attribute cross domain?